# Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property in angular 5

Tags: angular, ngfor

I am a beginner in angular, I developed a small application, but I have a problem, `*ngIf`, `*ngFor`, `nfForm` doesn't work ( I think error CommonModule )

file.html:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
              <div>
              <select class="form-control">
                <option selected value="">Select Project</option>
                <option *ngFor='let app of projetsa' [value]="app?.projectId">
                   {{app?.ProjetName}}
                </option>
              </select>
            </div>
            </div>
```

appModule.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
.
.
.
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [ BrowserModule, CommonModule,...],
  providers: [...],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

export function getBaseUrl() {
  return document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].href;
}
```

package.json :

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.7",
.
.
.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add BrowserModule to imports array in `@NgModule()` if it's the root module (AppModule), otherwise the CommonModule.

```
import {BrowserModule, CommonModule} from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, /* or CommonModule */],
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had missed to include CommonModule and could not figure out why.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `CommonModule` from `appModule.ts`because `CommonModule` (all the basics of Angular templating: bindings, *ngIf, *ngFor…), except in the first app module, because it’s already part of the `BrowserModule`.

> BrowserModule provides services that are essential to launch and run a
>   browser app.
>
> BrowserModule also re-exports CommonModule from @angular/common, which
>   means that components in the AppModule module also have access to the
>   Angular directives every app needs, such as NgIf and NgFor.

Also read [this](https://medium.com/@cyrilletuzi/understanding-angular-modules-ngmodule-and-their-scopes-81e4ed6f7407).

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `CommonModule` from `appModule.ts` and import it in the module where you have your `file.html`

Answer (score 1):

Adding this in the component.module.ts file should work:

```
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
})
```

Answer (score -1):

The `NgForOf` directive is used with `<ng-template>` only.

eg:

```
<ng-template ngFor let-app [ngForOf]="projetsa" let-i="index">
       <li>{{i}}  {{app}}</li>
  </ng-template>
```